Maui iOS UIApplication.Main() throiwing exception
I have a Xamarin.Forms app that I am porting over to MAUI. The android version works and builds fine. The iOS has a persistant problem whereby Program.Main(args) throws an exception. The watchdog on the iOS device kills the app before we can really step through anything.
Code:
using MyMauiApp;
using ObjCRuntime;
using System.Diagnostics;
using UIKit;

namespace MyMaui
{
    public class Program
    {
        // This is the main entry point of the application.
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // if you want to use a different Application Delegate class from "AppDelegate"
            // you can specify it here.
            try
            {
                UIApplication.Main(args, null, typeof(AppDelegate));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("*-*-*-*-*-*-*-");
                Debug.WriteLine(ex);
                Debug.WriteLine("*-*-*-*-*-*-*-");
            }
        }
    }
}

[0:] *-*-*-*-*-*-*-
[0:] System.TypeLoadException: Could not resolve type with token 01000005 from typeref (expected class 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.InternalsVisibleToAttribute' in assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51')
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributesBase(ICustomAttributeProvider , Type , Boolean )
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(ICustomAttributeProvider , Type , Boolean )
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetCustomAttributes(Type , Boolean )
   at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ReflectionExtensions.GetCustomAttributesSafe(Assembly assembly, Type attrType)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Internals.Registrar.RegisterAll(Assembly[] assemblies, Assembly defaultRendererAssembly, Type[] attrTypes, InitializationFlags flags, Action`1 viewRegistered, IFontRegistrar fontRegistrar)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Internals.Registrar.RegisterAll(Type[] attrTypes, InitializationFlags flags, IFontRegistrar fontRegistrar)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Internals.Registrar.RegisterAll(Type[] attrTypes, IFontRegistrar fontRegistrar)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility.Forms.RegisterCompatRenderers(IMauiContext )
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility.Forms.SetupInit(IMauiContext , Nullable`1 )
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility.Forms.Init(IActivationState , Nullable`1 )
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility.Hosting.AppHostBuilderExtensions.<>c.<OnConfigureLifeCycle>b__1_1(IMauiContext mauiContext)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ApplicationExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<CreatePlatformWindow>b__0(OnMauiContextCreated del)
   at Microsoft.Maui.LifecycleEvents.LifecycleEventServiceExtensions.InvokeLifecycleEvents[OnMauiContextCreated](IServiceProvider services, Action`1 action)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ApplicationExtensions.CreatePlatformWindow(IApplication application, UIWindowScene windowScene, NSDictionary[] states)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ApplicationExtensions.CreatePlatformWindow(IUIApplicationDelegate platformApplication, IApplication application, UIApplication uiApplication, NSDictionary launchOptions)
   at Microsoft.Maui.MauiUIApplicationDelegate.FinishedLaunching(UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)
   at MauiSalesSupportApp.AppDelegate.FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options) in C:\Users\myUser\Documents\Source-Repos\myRepo\mySolution\Platforms\iOS\AppDelegate.cs:line 70
   at UIKit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain(Int32 , String[] , IntPtr , IntPtr ) in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-macios/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:line 58
   at UIKit.UIApplication.Main(String[] , Type , Type ) in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-macios/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:line 94
   at myApp.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\myUser\Documents\Source-Repos\myRepo\myApp\Platforms\iOS\Program.cs:line 17
[0:] *-*-*-*-*-*-*-

We've tried cleaning and rebuilding the project.
I am using .NET 8.0.303.
iOS Version is 17.5.1.
Packages Include: ACR.UserDialogs (9.0.0), CommunityToolkit.Maui (9.0.2), CommunityToolkit.Mvvm (8.2.2), FFImageLoading.Maui (1.2.6), Microsoft.AppCenter (5.0.5), Microsoft.AppCenter.Crashes (5.0.5), Microsoft.AppCenter.Analystic (5.0.5), Microsoft.Maui.Controls (8.0.70), Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility (8.0.70), Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Maps (8.0.70), Microsoft.NET.ILLink.Tasks (8.0.7), MonkeyCache.SQLite(2.1.1), Newtonsoft.JSON(13.0.3), Prism.Core (9.0.462), Prism.DryIoc.Maui (9.0.462), Prism.Maui (9.0.462), Prism.Maui.Rx (9.0.462), SkiaSharp (2.88.8), Syncfusion.Licensing (26.1.42), Syncfusion.Maui.Calendar (26.1.42), Syncfusion.Maui.Core (26.1.42), Syncfusion.Maui.Inputs (26.1.42), Syncfusion.Maui.Popup (26.1.42), Syncfusion.Maui.TabView (26.1.42), Xam.Plugin.DeviceInfo (4.2.0), ZXing.Net.Maui (0.4.0), ZXing.Net.Maui.Controls (0.4.0).

Does this crash on a simulator or real device? What are the versions of Xcode and iOS?

@AlexandarMay-MSFT It's been primarily on a real iPhone 13 using pair to mac with the iPhone connected to the mac. When I try deploying to a simulator I get the error "Clang++ exited with code 1". XCode version is 15.4.

Thanks for your response, may I know what nuget packages have you installed? And what is your iOS version, have you tried to install  .NET 8.0.6 (SDK 8.0.301), see https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/20257#issuecomment-2139860744

@AlexandarMay-MSFT I have updated my post with this information. I am using sdk 8.0.303, so am using .net 8.0.7.

Since you've installed many nugget packages, it's hard to find which specific nugget package causes the crash. You may create a blank app and then add them one by one , configure them properly to detect the issue.

As a quick diagnostic step, try launching the app from your iPhone after you have deployed it from Visual Studio. When I did this, the app ran fine, but crashed if I tried to debug from Visual Studio, indicating it's a problem with VS being attached.
I was able to solve this problem by disabling hot reload:

In Visual Studio, go to Tools -> Options
Expand Debugging
Select XAML Hot Reload
Uncheck Android and iOS (.NET MAUI)

Click OK to apply your changes in the Options popup

This is annoying because if you are working on an Android project this also disables hot reload there, but at least it enables you to debug your code on iOS.
